# MySQL can't reliably get the auto inc value returns due to truncation exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using tomcat with connection pool and MySQL JDBCconnector

I get my connection do an insert and want the returned key value. This is done like this :

```
conn = ds.getConnection();
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("use "+dbname);
sql = sql.trim();
int res  = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
if (sql.toLowerCase().startsWith("insert") ) {
    rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys() ;
    if (rs.next())
    r=  rs.getString(1);
}
```

So this has been working fine and I get the ID returned.

If there is a DATA TRUNCATION EXCEPTION then although the insert succeeds I can no longer get the value of the returned key. So I end up with values in the database that I am not aware of.

I need to either get rid of the exception or maybe change the whole way I do this ?

I can fix the bean that does the update and the dbase data type - but I want a belt and braces way to make sure if I haven't done this right I can get the ID back as it did succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround your entire section with something like this

```
try{
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  //do stuff
  conn.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
  //failure logic
  try{
    conn.rollback();
  }catch(Exception e){
    //rollback fail logic
  }
  //more failure logic
}
```

That way, you only commit changes to the database if both succeed.

Comment: Don't forget about rollback

Comment: hi i tried that but the same issue still occurs. I dont get back the auto inc number, the sql succeeds ( its in the database ) with an exception thrown com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data truncated for column.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is correct, I forgot the actual part that rolled the data back, should be better now.

Comment: @user1882639 after you made an insert (successfully or with errors) the INNODB engine will already increment the value of the id. If you want to change that behavior, download the MySQL source code and do the necessary changes :). Now, why MySQL behave like that? Because two transactions could do an insert at the same time, so *rolling back* the auto generated ID for one will mean that it will have to do the same for the other concurrent insert, thus leading to bigger problems. Is it a big deal? In real world apps: no.

Comment: Sorry let me explain better. The insert succeeded yet the exception was still thrown. When the exception occurs its not possible to get back the incremented value as usual although the record is indeed in the table.  The autocommit and rollback dont seem to do anything desptie using InnoDB. So exception occurs and rollback doesnt roll anything back. The record is still in the table

Comment: @user1882639 This seems really odd. Are you sure you set `Connection#setAutoCommit(false)` before starting the DDL operations? Are you working with the right isolation level in both your JDBC configuration and your MySQL database? Have you monitored if these values are really inserted in the database?

Comment: they are definitely in the database. I see the exception thrown but I would expect the row to not be in the database as con.rollback() is called.   A good solution for me would be to only receive exceptions that result in a row not being inserted e.g. data truncation as a warn. Whilst I could do this in the catch block I still cant get the new inserted key which means I cant reference this insert for deletion or using further on.

Comment: @user1882639 I've just made a quick test based on what you said, and the rollback works neat for me. Please update your question (without removing its actual contents) and post your actual code in order to receive guidance. Also, make sure you're running this new code and not the old one.

Comment: The rollback works for me on a simple test as well, but if all you need is the latest entry, you could do `SELECT IDCOLUMNNAME from TABLENAME order by IDCOLUMNNAME desc limit 1` I wouldn't really recommend it in this case though, since you may get a completely different row than you expect if the database is being accessed rapidly. I agree with a more complete code post so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Hi ok my mistake the solution is perfect the issue is that on my test table the default engine was MyISAM from the laptop instance i was using. Change it to InnoDB ( which the live system is anyway ) and the rollback method worked very well. Thankyou very much for your time and help.